# How to create ASPX Page Dynamically

Tags: asp.net, dynamic

i have two controls on asp.net page , textbox and button and i want to write new page into textbox then when i hit the button i want to create new asp.net web page with textbox text. what do you want me to prefer to do this? is there any step by step tutorial or any code you have done before? thanks for asnwers.

ok more detail about what i want.

textbox control text is "contact" and i click my button control. button take textbox text "contact" and create new web form page which name is "contact.aspx and its code page contact.cs" . thats it. just create new web form page under root directory with button click.

maybe there is a single code line like

`Page pg =new Page();
pg.create();`

Comment: Do you just want to show the text to the user or do you want to actually create a new ASPX-Page in your project? (code generation?) I guess you want the first thing and should start reading an ASP.Net book or tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`File.WriteAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext.aspx) to write the contents of the textbox to any location that the application pool user has permissions to write to.

---

From your edit it appears that you are looking for a CMS/wiki kind of functionality. There is nothing like that built into the .NET framework.

I suggest you look for wiki software.

Comment: i dont wanna write textbox contents.i wanna create a new default.aspx page.and textbox context will replace "default" text.

Comment: @Erdinç - If the file you want to overwrite is in use, an exception will occur. As for my answer, it still seems to me to answer your question. Did you follow the link?

Comment: yeah i follow your link.but i just wanna create aspx and cs page like visual studio nothing else.not too complicated i guess.

Comment: @Erdinç - You are underestimating the amount of work VS does. It is also not very clear what you want - your question and the comments you made make it clear that your question doesn't have enough detail. How about you edit your question and add much more details about what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

No need to worry about big codes etc

You can create it with 2 simple steps explained in my blog

1. Create one empty page then copy it using Files concept. Save it as what ever name you want.
2. Try to change the content inside newly created page to Run smoothly

Please visit my blog for example solution

[Click here for Solution Post](http://myworkcodes.wordpress.com/2011/07/02/creating-asp-net-page-dynamically-using-dotnet-programe/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Page.ParseControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.parsecontrol.aspx) method.

Beware, it does not support everything you can do with a real ASPX or ASHX file, but it works for simple things. An example is available here: [Using Page.ParseControl to add new control from Control Tag](http://www.vikramlakhotia.com/Using_PageParseControl_to_add_new_control_from_Control_Tag.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There is very simple way to do that. It is working on principe to Copy one your Page, you should put Page with controls that you want to use on your other pages. So first you need `using System.IO;` then you need this code

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        File.Copy(Server.MapPath("") + "\\Submit.aspx", (Server.MapPath("") + "\\" + TextBox1.Text + ".aspx"));
        File.Copy(Server.MapPath("") + "\\Submit.aspx.cs", (Server.MapPath("")+ "\\" + TextBox1.Text + ".aspx.cs"));
        Response.Redirect(TextBox1.Text + ".aspx");
    }
    catch
    {
        Response.Write("<script>window.alert('This page is taken. Please change name!')</script>");
    }
}
```

As you can see, The page you are coping is called Submit, and new Name of your Page is called like textbox1.text.
I hope that this helped you and anyone else.